# jQuery format date min & max date jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hello I got a rather simple question. I was wondering why does this:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy,mm,dd', new Date("15-03-2016"))
```

not work? When I `console.log` this I will get the following output:

```
NaN,NaN,NaN
```

I need this to set the min and max dates of my Datepicker:

```
minDate: $.datepicker.formatDate('yy,mm,dd', new Date("15-03-2016")), 
maxDate: $.datepicker.formatDate('yy,mm,dd', new Date("19-03-2016")),
```

Why is this and what should I do? Do I have to convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because date is not able to parse the given format(`new Date("15-03-2016")` returns an Invalid Date object) so just parse the date

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy,mm,dd', $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', "15-03-2016"))
```

You can also pass the date object as the value for [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)/[maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

```
minDate: $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', '15-03-2016'),
```

Comment: Awesome. That just did the trick! Thank you for your explanation! That really helps!

Answer (score 0):

Date objects are created with the new Date() constructor.

There are 4 ways of initiating a date:

1. new Date()
2. new Date(milliseconds)
3. new Date(dateString)
4. new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

I think you are passing date in wrong format.